# Need to get the name of the Qari by the text from some photos

Tags: quran, source-identification, quran-recitation

I took photos from television when it was showing Quran recitation.
At the bottom the photos(I mean television screen) I think they are displaying the name of the Qari who was reciting the Quran.

I am adding 3 photos where there are the name of the different Qari in all photos.

[image]

[image]

[image]

but my problem is I am not a native Arabic speaker and I can't read Arabic in such form.

can anyone please tell me name of all the Qari from these 3 photos?

Answer (score 4):

The Qari in the first is:

[القارئ محمد المنشاوي](http://ar.islamway.net/scholar/1032)

Qari' Muhammad Al Minshawi

In the Second is:

[القارئ فارس عباد](http://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3_%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AF)

Qari Faris 'Abbad

in the third:

[القارئ عبد الله الجهني](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/index.php?page=souraview&qid=527&rid=1)

Qari' Abdullah Al Juhani

I hope this answers your question.